# Do functional equations with continuous functions always have continuous solutions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider two sets of continuous functions $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  $a_1 ... a_n$ and and lastly a continuous function $\mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ G. Then consider the functional equation:

$$ f(z) = G(f(a_1(z)), f(a_2(z)), ... f(a_n(z))) $$

[Credit to Hagen Von Eitzen for pointing this out] If this equation Does have a solution AT ALL then does there necessarily exist a solution to this equation which is continuous over some open subset $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$?

### My Ideas:

I want to say yes because continuity is preserved under composition and so perhaps arbitrary functional equations isn't such a large step from function composition?

Unfortunately this question did not come from any class or HW so I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: With $n=1$, $a_1(z)=z$, $G(z)=z+1$, there is no (continuous or not) solution ... So do you rather want to say: If there is a solution at all, then there is also a continuous solution?

Comment: ah! it seems I was careless to let $G$ be too generic. Good counterexample!

Comment: Yes your follow up would be my next question :)

Comment: I have a marvellous counterexample: $f(z)=f(e^iz)+|z|$. Unfortunately, this is not of the form you suggest :(

Comment: Seems unlikely this is true but a counterexample may be tricky to construct.  Certainly there are plenty of examples of "continuous" functional equations which have only discontinuous solutions, but maybe there is none with this specific form.

Comment: I *think* I have an example for $n=1$ where a global solution exists, but no *global* continuous solution. it is overly complicated for what it achieves, and in particular I guess this still allows a solution on some smaller ($a_1$-invariant) $D$, so I won't put it into an answer. Instead, it even strengthens my belief that @EricWofsey's suspicion is right